# Re-run Cypress test in Github Actions does not work

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions

I have a cypress workflow in Github and it runs nicely. But, when the e2e tests fail for some reason and I want to re-run them using the `re-run all jobs` button (below), the following message appears:

[image]

```
The run you are attempting to access is already complete and will not accept new groups.

The existing run is: https://dashboard.cypress.io/projects/abcdef/runs

When a run finishes all of its groups, it waits for a configurable set of time before finally completing. You must add more groups during that time period.

The --tag flag you passed was: 
The --group flag you passed was: core
```

What should I change in my configuration to make these possible? Sometimes the e2e fails because of a backend error that is fixed later.

I'd like to do this instead of a `force e2e` commit.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue before.
I think you can try to pass `GITHUB_TOKEN` or add a custom build id. It fixed my issue. Hoep it helps.
https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#custom-build-id

Answer (score 0):

Check your Cypress Dashboard subscription plan. Mine got the free plan full (500 test for free and I was running in 3 different browsers 57 tests, so it got full pretty quick since this is 171 tests in one run) and after that it didn't allowed me to keep running or re running more parallel tests. Test kept running but in 1 machine out of 4 in the first browser and stages for the other 2 browsers started failing, I was able to allow the pipeline to not be failing by passing continueOnError: true in the configuration.

Quick edit, I don't remember where but I read that you could also add a delay to your pipeline and/or reduce the default wait on the Dashboard which is 60s(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization#Run-completion-delay)